# Why Should We Hire You?

Tags: job-change, new-hires

I am moving to USA, and because of war I didn't finished my bachelor degree in business administrations and to be honest that's the best thing that happened to me. I've been into science most of my life, but here you can't choose what you want to study, they choose.

I worked as a network engineer for small company at beginning, then opened a small company for one year then close it because of war. I am travelling from country to other, so it's not legal to work anywhere.

Finally, I got my VISA to have a stable life. In the last years, I was studying alone from books about electronics, networking, micro-controllers, C, C++, VB.net, web developing, social media, automation, 3D designing, Linux operating, router hacking, etc. I made a lot of devices using my skills from routers, automation projects, and websites.

My problem is I am lost: the idea of being without a certificate make me think I am not good enough to make a company hire me. My skills are in different fields, and I am not focusing on one thing. If I want to be a C programmer, I am sure who have a certificate will be better than me, and the same thing in other fields.

This is a small sample project of mine: http://narzan.weebly.com

How can I get a job when I face this challenge?

Comment: While probably a duplicate question, it seems like OP is unsure whether his experience makes up for lack of qualifications. It seems more like a "How can I get a job with what I know" question. Very similar, but somewhat different, and probably a duplicate of yet another existing question. All the same, I think it's worth answering for the benefit of the OP, and anyone else in a similar situation. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is true that many companies screen candidates based on whether they have a degree or certificate, there are many that will hire you if you have the right skills. It does take work finding those companies and getting them to give you a chance to show what you know. Talk with everyone you know, and anyone you don't know who will give you a moment of their time. Let them know what you want to do, what you're good at. Ask them to keep you in mind if they hear of anything that comes up. Be willing to do some freelance or contract work for short periods of time. Who knows, you might be able to start your own business, with all your hardware experience?

You have to start making a name for yourself. You can do this by **volunteering in the community** where you live. There are plenty of social service departments that teach computer skills to the less fortunate, or that need technical work done, but can't afford to hire someone. You can **start a blog** focused on the area(s) of your expertise. You can **participate in forums** such as StackExchange, Reddit, etc. You can **start or make significant contributions to an open-source project.**

You might have to settle for temporary work in a different industry (restaurant, retail, custodial, landscaping, etc.) in order to earn money to live while you build up your technical reputation on the side. It won't take long.

Congratulations on getting your visa and taking such a huge leap of faith. All the best to you!

Comment: Your answer is amazing, It's like a life-time, scary to think about, but must be done, Thanks Kent :)